# pfSense - Unable to resolve the server's DNS address

Tags: dns, pfsense

I am trying to configure pfSense in vmware workstation 8 on Win 7 host. My internet connection is always-on static ip type so I am given range of IP addresses and gateway with DNS. But before I could access any website I need to do web-based authentication by putting in user credentials (user/pass) on the url given by ISP and I am ready to access any website. So, I can see a green lights on the pfSense homepage (webconfigurator) and I can also tracert DNS (as shown below) privided by ISP but it doesn't redirect to the ISP authentication page so I am not able to access any website. It shows "Unable to resolve the server's DNS address" in Chrome Browser. The redirect login url is https://loginbom.tataindicombroadband.in:8443/home". Is it to do with firewall settings?

```
C:\\Users\0msai>tracert 172.31.6.125
Tracing route to 172.31.6.125 ouer a maximum of 39 hops
1 1 ms <1 ms <1 ms cafe.ch0k01ade [192.168.1.1]
2 53 ms 28 ms 75 ms 59.165.4.65.man*static.usn1.net.in [59.165.4.65
3 7 ms 18 ms 4 ms 172.24.235.17
4 2 ms 37 ms 239 ms 172.24.235.1
5 49 ms 24 ms 15 ms 172.31.151.37
6 39 ms 9 ms 11 ms 172.31.67.194
7 21 ms 21 ms 144 ms 172.31.67.254
8 27 ms 23 ms 42 ms 172.31.33.58
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First guess, you didn't define DNS servers under System>General Setup.

Comment: It seems it was blocking the access to login web page as it was considering it to be "DNS Rebinding attack". When I disabled it in the System->Advanced configuration page, it worked.